# joining str_replace with strtolower

Tags: php, str-replace, lowercase

Simple one hopefully, is there a way I can use strtolower and str_replace together. At the moment I am changing the value of a variable and declaring it seperately, and thought if i could do this together it would be more efficient?

```
$afixteam = str_replace(" ","-",$fixData['ateam_name']);
$afixteamlink = strtolower($afixteam);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should do it. You can run methods within methods as follows, condensing to a single line.

```
$afixteam = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$fixData['ateam_name']));
```

Comment: Excellent. Remember you can employ this all over php to keep your line count down, but your code may suffer from poor readability if used too much!! Make sure you accept one of the answers, it's just the way we do things ;) click the tick!

Answer (score 5):

```
$afixteam = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$fixData['ateam_name']));
```

How you would with most things.